# What's the surface area of a Klein bottle?

Tags: area, klein-bottle

I am creating a 3D model of a Klein Bottle based on the Robert Israel formula:
[image: Robert Israel Klein Bottle]

Then I need to apply algorithms on the model and I need to know the surface area of this 3D model, then what's the formula to calculate the surface area of it??

Comment: This is a parametrization. Just compute the Jacobian determinant andintegrate over the region of parametrization.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Thanks for the instant reply. Is it possible to calculate for me?  Jacobian determinant and integrate are long time knowledge to recall for me I only need to know the exact surface area of it to apply my coding algorithms.